# decimal value addition not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function sum() {
     a = Number(document.getElementById("rate_ts").value);
     b = Number(document.getElementById("discount").value);
     c = a - (Number(a) * Number(b) / 100);
     d = Number(document.getElementById("ocharge").value) + c + Number(document.getElementById("pay_amt").value);
     tax = (Number(a) * Number(12.36) / 100);
     e = tax + d;
     document.getElementById("net_amt").value = e;
 }
```

this code is not working right......i want to add tax and for that i have given 12.36 but it is not returning anything..plz help

Comment: What do you mean by `not returning anything`?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Dwqj4/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
function sum() {
     a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rate_ts").value);
     b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("discount").value);
     c = a - (a * b / 100);
     d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ocharge").value) + c + parseFloat(document.getElementById("pay_amt").value);
     tax = a * 12.36 / 100;
     e = tax + d;
     document.getElementById("net_amt").value = e.toFixed(2);
 }
```

If you want only two decimal point value then use `number.toFixed(2)`

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwqj4/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

[parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> Summary
>
> The parseFloat() function parses a string argument and returns a
>   floating point number.

```
$('#three').click(function (e) {
     a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rate_ts").value);
     b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("discount").value);

    console.log(a+' | '+b);
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/Z8vjD/)